# How to Migrate oracle 6i forms into oracle Apex?

Tags: migration, oracle-apex, oracleforms

I am having problem in converting my Oracle 6i forms into Apex, first we convert fmb file into xml file where apex read that file. for that purpose in cmd we give path (oracle\middleware\summit) what is summit in this path and i could not find that file in oracle\middleware.

but i can't understand which path i have to give in cmd. But there is a summit file that i could not find. Can you please guide me about paths to convert oracle 6i to oracle Apex?

I am expecting that someone can guide me about paths to convert oracle 6i to oracle Apex.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done that (migrate Forms, especially not an *ancient* 6i version, to Oracle Apex).

However, here's a series of articles written by Monica Godoy ([Modernizing an Oracle Forms Application to an Oracle APEX Application](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/modernizing-an-oracle-forms-application-to-an-oracle-apex-application)).

Among other things, she says:

> To create the Migration Project in APEX, convert your Forms files to XML using the **Forms2XML Conversion Tool**.  This tool was introduced in **Oracle9i Oracle Developer Suite** and produces an XML file that has the same base name as the Forms file with an .xml extension.

As you're on Forms 6i, maybe you should first migrate to Forms 9i. Though, I'm not sure you can find installation any longer, that's also unsupported version. You could contact Oracle Support and - presuming you have a valid contract - they might provide 9i installation files.

Answer (score 0):

There are no easy ways to go from Forms to APEX with a click of a button. You are moving from a client server type of application to a web based application and that implies a lot of things.  If you need assistance and guidance with your approach you can reach out to insum since they have been involved with those kind of projects for over a decade now.

Check this out : https://www.insum.ca/formsmigration/

Answer (score 0):

Why are you wasting time and money trying to convert to something else?  What you should consider is upgrading to a current and supported version.  Once upgraded, carefully review your application and identify areas that could use improvements, both in functionality and UI.  Compared to the version you are using (6.0.8), there are many improvements to Forms both in functionality and UI.  In the coming version(s), extensive improvements to the UI are planned, so being on the latest version now will make moving to the coming versions easier when they become available.  More details about the latest version can be found on the product page.

https://www.oracle.com/application-development/technologies/forms/forms.html